# clang-format add inconsistent line break in function declaration

Tags: c++, clang-format

I like to use clang-format on a large code base for C/C++.

I don't understand why clang-format is sometimes giving me this inconsistent format

```
virtual void someReallyLongFunctionName(
    float* aaaaa, float* aaaaaaaaaaaaa, float* bbbbb, float* bbbbb, float* bbbbbbb, int* ccccc, int* cccccc,
    int* ccccc, float* cccccccc, float* cccccccc, float* ccccccc, float* ccccccccc, float* cccccc, float* ccccccccc,
    float* ccccccccccc, float* c, float* ccc, float* ccccc, float* ccccc, int* cccc, float* dddddddddddddddddddddd,
    float* ddddd, float* dddd, float* ffffffffffff, int* fffffff, float* fffffff, float* ffffffffffffffffffffff,
    int* ffffff, int* fffff, int* fffffffffffffff, int ffsddffffffffff, float* aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa,
    float* aaaaaaaaaaaa, int* aaaaaaaaaaaa, logical* aaaaa, float* bbbbbbbbb) const = 0;

virtual void shortName(float* aaaaa, float* aaaaaaaaaaaaa, float* bbbbb, float* bbbbb, float* bbbbbbb, int* ccccc,
                       int* cccccc, int* ccccc, float* cccccccc, float* cccccccc, float* ccccccc, float* ccccccccc,
                       float* cccccc, float* ccccccccc, float* ccccccccccc, float* c, float* ccc, float* ccccc,
                       float* ccccc, int* cccc, float* dddddddddddddddddddddd, float* ddddd, float* dddd,
                       float* ffffffffffff, int* fffffff, float* fffffff, float* ffffffffffffffffffffff,
                       int* ffffff, int* fffff, int* fffffffffffffff, int ffsddffffffffff, float* aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa,
                       float* aaaaaaaaaaaa, int* aaaaaaaaaaaa, logical* aaaaa, float* bbbbbbbbb) const = 0
```

I used `clang-format -style="{BasedOnStyle: Google, ColumnLimit: 120, IndentWidth: 4}"`, version 4.0.0.

Which switch or penalty value can I use to enforce that also `someReallyLongFunctionName` looks like this

```
virtual void someReallyLongFunctionName(float* aaaaa, float* aaaaaaaaaaaaa, ...
```

and no additional line break is introduced.

I know that the interface is violating the c++ core guidelines. Nevertheless, this legacy code shall be formated consistently.

Comment: You should read the doc.  https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AlignAfterOpenBracket: DontAlign` is enforcing the desired behaviour.